# Reading from stdin reads no data when run with `cargo run` and Rust 1.9 nightly

Tags: rust, stdin, rust-cargo

Update: This seems to be a cargo bug. See the answer link for more details.

I upgraded from Rust 1.6 to 1.9 in order to use a package. However, the terminal no longer waits for input when reading from standard input. This issue seems to only be with `cargo run` (cargo 0.10.0-nightly (25e1301 2016-03-25)); everything works fine when I run the binary file directly.

I am using almost the same example as the one given on the [documentation for `Stdin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html):

```
use std::io;

let mut input = String::new();
match io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
    Ok(n) => {
        println!("{} bytes read", n);
        println!("{}", input);
    }
    Err(error) => println!("error: {}", error),
}
```

Running this example with `cargo run` prints `0 bytes read`.

I have both the 1.6 and 1.9 compiler on my computer and the code works with  1.6 just fine. I tried using 1.9 on both Windows and Linux with the same results.

Why is this happening and how should stdin be handled in Rust 1.9?

Comment: Can’t reproduce on nightly from a week ago, updating to confirm…

Comment: Still can’t reproduce with latest nightly, using `rustc` or `rustc -O`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Okay it is working fine when I use `rustc` but not when I use `cargo run`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of cargo that you are using: `cargo --version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was just filed: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2530

Seems like the same issue. Probably a bug.